# Get pointer to constant from a method as pointer to pointer

Tags: c++

I need to get a pointer to a constant from a method. The pointer to constant cannot be returned as return value.

What should be the signature of **Getpointer** method?

```
struct xyz
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

xyz myruntime;
void Getpointer(xyz **pz);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const xyz *ptr = NULL;  
    Getpointer(&ptr);

    return 0;
}

void Getpointer(const xyz const ** pz)
{
    *pz = &myruntime;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function prototype

```
void Getpointer(xyz **pz);
```

doesn't match the function definition

```
void Getpointer(const xyz const ** pz)
```

Also, `const xyz` is the same as `xyz const`, and `const xyz const` is redundant. So the function prototype should be

```
void Getpointer(const xyz ** pz);
```

and the function definition should be similar, but without the semicolon at the end.

Comment: thanks.. I tried different options without changing the function declaration

Answer (score 2):

You could also use reference in C++

```
  void Getpointer(const xyz *&pz)
  {
      pz = &myruntime;
  }
```

and then call it as

```
 const xyz *ptr = NULL;  
 Getpointer(ptr);
```